# C# Cannot make a custom richtextbox in a class

Tags: c#, error-handling, richtextbox

I have been working on my code for a couple of hours now and want to create a master copy of a richtextbox, but it keeps getting overwritten if I do this: "MasterText.ControledText = ListTextBox;". If I don't do that I get the error.

This is the class method I made for it:

```
    public static class MasterText
    {
        public static RichTextBox ControledText;
    }
```

and here is where I am getting the error:

```
    private void WordList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\Temp\DWList.txt")){
            string s = "";
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"C:\Windows\Temp\DWList.txt")){
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null){
                    ListTextBox.Text += s + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                sr.Dispose();
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        if (ListTextBox.Text != null && ListTextBox.Text != "")
            MasterText.ControledText.Text = ListTextBox.Text;
    }
```

I keep getting an error that I have no idea what it mean:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in FindWord.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have created a static variable and trying to access with out initializing it . Try changing to the following

```
public static RichTextBox ControledText = new RichTextBox();
```

you can check the same for your ListTextBox also

Comment: Wow, thank you. There is nothing this website and people can't solve

Comment: good to hear.. if the issue is solved.please mark the question as answered. good luck..